# PHP cURL cannot connect to IIS on local machine

Tags: php, curl, iis, localhost

I have a PHP script that tries to connect with an other PHP script located on a IIS installation running on a local machine in my office using the cURL protocol but fails to do so.

Local configuration:
I've opened the port 8789 on the firewall, I made the router redirect correctly to the IP of the machine running IIS and I've set the default port of IIS to 8789. 
If I try to connect to the script (93.144.xxx.xxx:8987/curl_response.php) through a browser I get the resulting output so this setup is working correctly.

When I try to run the PHP script on a remote webserver though it gives my either **cUrl error (#7): couldn't connect to host** or **cUrl error (#28): connect() timed out!** (I'm trying different webservers)

The curl part of my PHP script is the following:

```
$url = 'http://93.144.xxx.xxx:8789/curl_response.php';

$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $rurl);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 8789);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if ($response === FALSE) {
    printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($curl),
           htmlspecialchars(curl_error($curl)));
    rewind($verbose);
    $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);

    echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog),"</pre>\n";   
}else{
    curl_close($curl);
    // trim response (serialized array)
    $response = trim($response);
    // unserialize
    $response = unserialize($response);
    print_r($response);
}
```

I've tried several different CURLOPT_ configurations and I've even tried using a dyndns host instead of the IP, but to no avail.

Is there a IIS configuration to set so it will accept incomming cURL requests or is there a specific header to be sent though cURL?

Thanks.

Comment: Just can you check by increasing timeout .. increase it to 60 and test. and also remove the last curl option CURLOPT_PORT

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $rurl);
```

Should be:

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

---

Here's an example of a *working* curl request:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://thepointless.com:80/';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 80);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

print $response;

?>
```

It's just like yours, except three things:

- It's connecting to port 80
- It's not setting STDERR
- **The typo is fixed**

Comment: typo slipped in while altering the variables used for clearity purposes.

Comment: @user700119 have you tried starting with a known-working example ... maybe copy/paste mine and see if that works? ... and then making *small* changes and retesting to see which change is the breaking change?

Answer (score 0):

Run cURL from the command line with --verbose to see more detailed information.

And check if ISS it's with cURL enabled:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```